# Arschmitz jQuery Mobile Datepicker format Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the Datepicker from
https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper
for jQuery Mobile.

```
<label for="nachname">Geburtsdatum</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" data-role="date" name="gebdat">
```

with

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').date({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val()
    });
</script>
```

but the format is still 04/16/2014.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please be more specific about where you're seeing this problem?  What's the format of the value displayed in the field versus the format of the submitted date.

Comment: Please always proof-read your OP... the Github link you posted was giving a 404 error until I fixed it.

Comment: The Link works for me. What can be the problem with it?

I want to display it 2014-04-07 but it is displayes 04/07/2014

Comment: [Your link was broken until I fixed it](https://github.com//jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper).  (It was giving a 404 error because it was  missing the username, `/arschmitz/`, url segment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--jQuery-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI-->
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/master/ui/datepicker.js"></script>
<!--jQuery Mobil--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Mobile Datepicker -->
<link href="http://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/master/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/master/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Start</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content"> 
<form action="this.php" method="post" data-ajax="true">
<label for="gebdat">Date</label>
<input type="text" name="gebdat" data-role="date" data-date-format="yy-mm-dd" >

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-icon="edit" aria-disabled="false">Save</button>

</form>
 </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>End</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

With `data-date-format="yy-mm-dd"` you set the format and not with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine. The page says its an extension of jquery ui base, so bascially I followed how jquery ui sets its format.

```
$( "#startDate" ).datepicker({"dateFormat": "yy/mm/dd"});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both of the above methods are not working for me. Any other idea please.

Comment: Here is my HTML for the datepicker 
`<input type="text" id="txtSurveyAllottedOn" name="SurveyAllottedOn" data-mini="true" data-role="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" data-date-format="dd/mm/yy" />`

Here is the JS
`$('#txtSurveyAllottedOn').datepicker({"dateFormat" : "dd/mm/yy"});`